# Woher kommt "Springinsfeld"?

Tags: etymology

Woher kommt diese Phrase bzw. das Wort [Springinsfeld](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springinsfeld)? Es bezeichnet jemanden, der *sorglos* ist oder sich *unbedacht* verhält.

Vgl. En. *fling in the hay, roll in the hay, to roll in the hay*.

Comment: @IQV, it's rare, I heared it, had to ask what it means, and got an anecdote to hear, that doesn't really matter, but was in line with *sorglos*. Or do you mean *fling in the hay*? I have trouble finding a definition, but found (only) three citations, at least one of which fits my association. Since *fling* can mean affair, and I have read *fling in the hay* in that sense before, I should note that it might mean a "Seitensprung". That theme would also fit an association of the *needle* in the haystack as a *traitor* or *infiltrator*, but only thematically.

Comment: Wenn man nach der genauen Herkunft fragt, muss klar sein, was denn die ungefähre Herkunft ist, was hier nicht der Fall ist. Ohne einen Maßstab kann man nicht urteilen, ob die Antwort genauer ist als ein unterstelltes Vorwissen. - Bezug zur Nadel im Heuhaufen besteht keiner, außer dass alte Sprichwörter natürlich oft dem bäuerlichen Raum entstammen, in dem vor 200 und mehr Jahren über 80% der Deutschen noch beschäftigt waren. Außer mit dem Feld wäre, wie von FfF bereits angedeutet, das Schlachtfeld gemeint, dann besteht auch von da kein Zusammenhang.

Comment: @user-unkown eher als für "genau" [sic!] (nicht "genauer") zählt das Argument für einen Bezug zu einem anderen Sprichwort. Wenn die Herkunft von zwei Phrasen unklar ist, kann ein gemeinsamer Ursprung nicht ausgeschloasen werden. Im 16. JH gab es zumindest auch die Nadel in der Wiese ("meadow")--näher an Feld als "haystack".

Comment: Vgl. *Woll-lust*, lol.

Comment: Vgl. *flink, schnelle Nummer*. Backref [en.SE / fling in the hay](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488134/fling-in-the-hay).

Comment: FWIW, [*spring-in-'t-veld*](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/niederl%C3%A4ndisch-deutsch/spring-in-%27t-veld) gibt es im Niederländischen auch, mit der gleichen Bedeutung.

Comment: Hmm... nicht ganz die gleiche Bedeutung: "ein lebhaftes, fröhliches (sorgloses) Kind." Hat in Holland wohl nix mit Soldaten, Landsknechte oder Handwerksburschen zu tun.

Comment: Vectory: Also Springinsfeld kann einen gemeinsamen Ursprung mit der Nadel im Heuhaufen haben, oder mit jedem anderen Sprichwort, für das der Ursprung nicht bekannt ist? Schön. Oder mit "Nadel in der Wiese", das mir völlig unbekannt ist. "Nadel in der Wiese" hilft uns aber nicht weiter, weil wir jetzt 2 Fragen haben: Hat Springinsfeld was mit N.i.d.W. zu tun und hat N.i.d.W. was mit Nadel im Heuhaufen zu tun? -- Fragen der Art "Was bedeutet xy genau?" oder "Woher kommt ... genau?" - wie genau brauchst Du es denn? Aufs Bundesland, den Landkreis, auf 2km genau, auf den Meter genau?

Comment: @user-unknown: Dass die "meadow" etwas mit der Nadel zu tun haben könnte, wurde in der [entsprechenden Frage ](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/121841?noredirect=1) offensichtlich, die hier auch verlinkt war, bevor ein Mod redaktionel tätig wurde--übereifrig meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach--die dir aber ohnehin bekannt sein sollte. Also was soll die rhethorische Frage? Ein subtiler Hinweis auf den Mangel deutscher Entsprechungen auf "Wiese"? Das bringt uns zu deiner ersten Frage. *Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence*.

Comment: "genau" bedeutet hier *genau genug, um die hypothetischen Zusammenhänge auszuschließen*. Da das nicht immer möglich ist, ist es durchaus eine schwierige Frage, bzw. ist eine entsprechende Antwort--nebenbei ohne stichfesten Beleg--schwerlich zu akzeptieren. Das Dilemma löst sich immerhin durch einfaches Ausblenden und natürliches Vergessen.

Comment: Nur nebenbei: im Spanischen ist das 'spring ins feld' ein Ausdruck für 'teilnehmen', während es im Lateinischen auch ein Ausdruck für 'kämpferisch teilnehmen' ist. span: https://www.linguee.com.ar/espanol-ingles/traduccion/salta+al+campo.html  ;  lat: campum prosilit

Answer (score 3):

Also laut Deutschem Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm handelt es sich bei *Springinsfeld* ursprünglich um den Namen eines Landsknechts. Dieser Eigenname geht auf die imperativische Phrase "Spring ins Feld!" im Sinne von 'eile ins Feld (also in den Krieg)!' zurück. Entsprechend finden sich auch Bildungen wie *Renninsland* oder *Hüpfinsholz*. Aber das wurde im Wesentlichen ja bereits von Hubert angesprochen.

In den literarischen Quellen erscheint dieser Name zuerst bei Hans Jakob Christoffel Grimmelshausen (um 1622 - 1676): "Springins-feld, der ein abgefäumter ertzvogel war und kein latein verstunde." (Hans Jakob Christoffel Grimmelshausen, Der abenteuerliche Simplicissimus, 17. Jh.) Später findet sich der Name dann als Beinamen von Personen und schließlich wurde er verallgemeinernd auf vor allem junge, fröhliche Menschen übertragen. Zum Beispiel bei Goethe: "sieh nur! ein paar artige knaben sitzen auf dem bocke, der eine springt herunter, die kutsche fährt langsam, er kommt auf's haus zu. das ist ein springinsfeld! da ist er schon." (Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, Was wir bringen, Dritter Auftritt, Anfang 19. Jh.)

Im Gegenwartsdeutschen ist dieses Wort bereits etwas veraltet und wird nur noch selten, meist scherzhaft, benutzt.

Hier die Quelle (Online-Version des Deutschen Wörterbuchs):

http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=springinsfeld

Comment: Du kannst den Link gerne als Quelle angeben, aber deine Antwort muss auch vollständig sein, ohne dass man dem Link folgt. Die verlinkte Seite könnte schon morgen einen anderen Inhalt haben, dann wäre deine Antwort wertlos. Deine Antwort wird aber hoffentlich auch in noch in einigen Jahrzehnten gelesen werden. Also editiere bitte deine Antwort und schreib hinein was deiner Ansicht nach die gestellte Frage beantwortet.

Comment: @Hubert: Danke für den Hinweis! Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend angepasst.

Comment: Eine regelmäßige Verwendung des Wortes im Gegenwartsdeutsch findet sich in den deutschen Übersetzungen der Disney-Comics. Dort ist der Begriff relativ geläufig.

Comment: Bemerke, Grimm schreibt "*ursprünglich* wol *name eines landsknechtes*". Dabei lese ich "wohl" als *wahrscheinlich, ziemlich sicher, könnte mich täuschen, nichts genaues weiß man nicht.* Andere bisher vorgebrachte Quellen fußen sicherlich darauf, und fügen der ausführlichen Besprechung leider nicht die nötige Sicherheit hinzu. Daher kann ich soweit keine Antwort akzeptieren. Dass der Eigenname der Ursprung sein sollte ist auch eine völlig falsche Lesung der Quelle. Dort wird nur auf die Bildung der Wortform verwiesen, die hier aber zweitrangig ist.

Comment: Offensichtlich war der Name schon immer mehr oder weniger scherzhaft. Meiner Lesart nach handelt es sich um eine Bezeichnung, die durch die Landsknechte verbreitet wurde. Weiteres ist jedoch ungewiss. Die hier genannten Zitate sind 17. und 18.JH also weit später als die ersten Belege. Die Daten der Belege sind bei Grimm leider nicht direkt zu belegen. Eine Darstellung der Entstehung entnehme ich denen ohnehin nicht.

Comment: Grimm verweist wegen der Namen auf [Grimm, Grammatik Bd. 2, p. 962](www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/grimm_grammatik02_1826?p=980). Dort werden solche Formen bis auf das 13 JH zurückgeführt (Störenfried, Vergissmeinnicht). Viele der Namen scheinen poetisch (Namn von Riesen, Schall-den-Wald), oder verballhornte Varianten anderer Namen (so wie "-walt" herkömmlich meist eher für Kraft, etc.steht) bzw. fremder Ortsnamen in Nachnamen ("wart-ein-weil"), wobei ich auch "irrensrit" (*-Ried*), "leimenzaun" (*Zaun, town*), "wahsengaul" (*Gau*), laerenbiutel (vgl. *Eimsbüttel* ~ *Busch*) dazu zähle.

Comment: Soweit ich das beurteilen kann, scheint es also möglich, dass die herangezogenen Befunde allesamt nicht direkt die Verwendung unter den Landsknechten bezeugen, und poetische Dichtungen auf eine ganz andere Bedeutung sein könnten. Zudem ist "Feld" als Ortsbezeichnung äußerst häufig, somit wäre zumindest die absurde Komposition erklärt. Sicher ist es jedoch nicht.

Comment: @vectory: Ja, das stimmt. Im Deutschen Wörterbuch steht "wohl", was darauf hinweist, dass man sich nicht völlig sicher ist. Auf 100 %ige Sicherheit wird man bei der Erklärung von Etymologien bzw. Wortherkunft meistens verzichten müssen. Man kann lediglich die Erklärung akzeptieren, die einem als am plausibelsten erscheint. Natürlich besteht die Möglichkeit, dass *Springinsfeld* ursprünglich anders bzw. auch in anderen Kontexten verwendet wurde, als jenem des *Soldaten- oder Kriegswesens*. Die ältesten Belege für dieses Wort weisen allerdings in diesen Bereich.

Comment: @vectory: Wieso sollten die genannten Zitate "weit später als die ersten Belege" sein? Für das Hochdeutsche ist das 17. Jh. der früheste Zeitraum, in dem dieses Wort bzw. dieser Name belegt ist. Ende 16. Jh. gibt es dann noch etwas Niederdeutsches, aber das ist es dann auch schon.

Answer (score 1):

Der Begriff *»ein Springinsfeld«* wurde im 16. Jahrhundert noch

> ein springe ynt velt

geschrieben und ist aus dem Imperativ

> spring ins Feld!

entstanden.

Damit bezeichnete man früher Soldaten und Landsknechte, die recht sorglos ins Kampfgebiet zogen. Später übertrug sich der Begriff auf alle umbekümmerten Menschen.

Heute wird der Begriff zwar seltener verwendet, aber wenn man ihn verwendet, meint man damit noch immer, dass die mit diesem Wort bezeichnete Person sich potentiellen Gefahren aussetzt, ohne vorher lange über diese Gefahren nachzudenken, oder komplexere Aktivitäten ausführen, ohne dafür einen detaillierten Plan zu haben.

---

Ich bin gebeten worden, meine Quellen nicht nur in den Kommentaren, sondern auch in der Antwort selbst zu nennen. Bitteschön: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springinsfeld), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Springinsfeld) und [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Springinsfeld).

Bei DWDS muss man den Etymologie-Block aufklappen, die gesuchten Informationen stehen ganz unten in diesem Block.

Comment: Dass der Begriff auf die Landsknechte zurückgeht ist unzweifelhaft. Allerdings denke ich nicht, dass dieser die heutige Bedeutung hat, weil diese sorglos/leichtsinnig in den Kampf zogen. Dafür galten sie als zu diszipliniert und kampfstark.

Comment: Ob dies originär ist, wird nicht gesagt. Tatsächlich liegt gar keine Quelle vor, die irgendwas sagen könnte. Wie der Imperativ Verwendung gefunden haben sollte, erschließt sich mir ohne weiteres leider nicht. Ich denke dabei immernoch eher an einen "Sprung ins Feld", wie "Schuss in den Ofen".

Comment: Der Vergleich ist nicht mal abwegig, vgl. *Schuss*, En. *snap-shot*, *flick* "Foto, Film; schnelle Bewegung" (vgl. *Flackern*), *fling (in the hay)*, *fling* "to throw, often violently; violent motion", *flinch* "(weg)zucken", *flitch* "Speckstreifen" (Vgl. *Fleisch*?), De. *flattern, flittern, flitzen, Flittchen, flirt*, Lat. *flingo* "to strike*, *conflict*. Mir kommt leider immerwieder der "Verschlag" in den Sinn, *Schlag* ist so ein vielfältiges Wort. Vgl. auch "sich hinflacken, hinhauen, ins Bett werfen", s. a. "Heia machen" (wegen *hauen*, En. *hew*). Sind diese Lanzmänner Schnarchnasen?

Comment: Ich verbinde mit "Springinsfeld" nicht unbedingt jemanden der sich *leichtsinnig* in Gefahr begibt, sonder nur jemanden der *leichtfüßig*, *sorglos* ist.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis etwas abdällig, spöttisch oder ironisch ist es meiner Erfahrung nach aber durchaus, weniger positiv.

Comment: Wegen "Imperativ" vgl. *Guckindieluft, Tunichtgut*, ... aber einfach auch bspw. *Prellbock* das sicher nur auf den Stamm reduziert. Imperativbildung wird üblicher Weise nicht groß erklärt oder von anderen Formbildungen abgeleitet, also ist ein Vergleich nur schwer möglich. Das *-in-* trägt natürlich zum Eindruck einer Phrase bei, aber ... woher kommt eigentlich *Springfield* (cf. die Simpsons).

Comment: @vectory: für mich nicht, aber das vielleicht nur, weil es in meiner Muttersprache nur positive Konnotationen hat: fröhlich, lebhaft, sorglos.

Comment: @Hubert: Klingt, als hättest Du dafür einen oder mehrere Belege. Hast Du? Welche?

Comment: @Hubert "..-  wurde **im 16. Jahrhundert** noch *ein springe ynt velt* geschrieben" ist eine kühne und komplett unzulässige Behauptung. Wenn GRIMM schreibt: *vgl. noch nd.*, dann steht *nd.* für niederdeutsch, nicht für neuhochdeutsch. Vll. ließe sich mehr als eine Belegstelle für diese Schreibung finden, aber selbst 2 oder 10 würden nicht deine Behauptung "im 16. Jh." rechtfertigen. [rudeness removed by moderator]

Comment: @multiplexetliber: Dein Ton gefällt mir überhaupt nicht. Wenigstens wurde die Beleidigung am Ende deines Kommentars gelöscht, aber auch den Rest hätte man sachlicher formulieren können. Zum Inhalt: Die *"kühne und komplett unzulässige"* Behauptung, dass das damals so geschrieben wurde, **stammt 1:1 aus dem [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Springinsfeld).** Bitte beschwere dich dort, statt hier Leute zu beleidigen, die in ihrer Freizeit und ohne Gegenleistung Sachverhalte recherchieren und versuchen sie möglichst korrekt wiederzugeben.

Comment: @Hubert Auch deine nächste Behauptung ist falsch. Im DWDS steht unmissverständlich, dass die Schreibung *ein springe ynt velt* im 16. Jh. **vorkam**, nicht, dass dies ein Jahrhundert lang die generelle Schreibweise war, wie du zuvor behauptet hattest. Da fällt mir doch dies ein: *Wer nit vor gürt / ee dann er rytt // Und ʃych verʃicht vorhyn by zyt // Des ʃpott man / falt er an eyn ʃytt.* Dies zur Bitte [to] "bring your sense of humor". :-)